# NiFi || I have a requirement where i need to schedule a flow biweekly Monday & friday for every hour but in different timezone

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to schedule a flow Bi-weekly for monday & friday for every hour.

0 11 * ? * 2,6

But the issue I am having is in timezone , i want the same in IST while it is running in UTC.

I guess there's an option to change timestamp in Bootstrap.conf file but i have many other flows which are  running as per UTC scheduling.

Can anyone tell me any feasible solution as I am blocked.

Answer (score 0):

@Ashu

This is a very edge type use case, when conflicting with other flows.   Can you not determine the correct time in UTC?

Another idea I have used in the past:  if you cannot control the flow in nifi,  perhaps you can rethink the trigger method for starting the flow.    For example:  instead of start of flow from starting processor on cron,  make the flow always on but started by trigger on existence of a file (List/fetch File).  Then use a separate method outside of nifi to create that file at the time that you want.   Now Nifi will only kick off the flow when the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the job as 30 00 * ? * 2,6 , as per UTC Timezone.

which would run every 1 hour monday and friday.

1. 2020-10-23 Fri 00:00:30
2. 2020-10-23 Fri 01:00:30
3. 2020-10-23 Fri 02:00:30
4. 2020-10-23 Fri 03:00:30
5. 2020-10-23 Fri 04:00:30

01AM UTC is 5:30AM IST, which will run your workflow from 5:30AM IST every hour